# Making smart multilevel histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm using RStudio Version 0.98.1028 on windows.
I'd like to make multilevel histogram using ggplot2. Let's say I have a 4D data frame like this:

```
facet <- as.factor(rep(c('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'), each = 4, times = 3))
group <- as.factor(rep(c('X', 'Y'), each = 2, times = 9))
type <- as.factor(rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 1, times = 18))
day <- as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 12)

df = data.frame(facet = facet, group = group, type = type, day = day, value = abs(rnorm(36)))
```

I'd like to make histograms of `x = day` vs `y = value` in 3 facets, corresponding to `facet`, grouping by `group` and filling by `type`. In other words I'd like to pile up `a` and `b` in a single bar, but keeping separated bars for `X` and `Y`. It would look something like

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(day, value, group = group, fill = type))
g + geom_histogram(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
    facet_grid(facet ~ .)
```

Unfortunately with the `dodge` option I get unstacked histograms, while without I get 4 bars at each day. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Using excel one facet should look something like this

[image]

Thanks in advance!

EB

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are exactly looking for - can you provide a picture of the Excel chart?

Comment: I agree with @CMichael, it would be easier to understand what you are looking for if you include a figure of the Excel chart ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe your question is related to [this one on the ggplot group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/bBPXtrrJrrI).
A possible solution is the following:

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(group, value, fill = type))
g + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
    facet_grid(facet ~ day)
```

It's suboptimal because you are using two facets, but in this way you obtain this figure: 
[image]

Comment: Almost! Only I'd like to have just the three main facets!

Comment: I think that you can only try to "hide" the day facet removing white spaces and labels at this point...

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Matteo your specific wish is probably not directly achievable with the tooling provided by `ggplot2`. A little bit of hacking provided below which may point in the right direction - I am not endorsing it too much but I just spent a couple of minutes playin, around with it. Maybe you can pick up a few of the elements.

I combined group and day into a single factor and when plotting replaced the x-labels manually with the (non-unique) group names. I then included (in a lazy manner) day labels. I still feel day x facet is the way you should proceed.

```
df$combinedCategory <- as.factor(paste(df$day,df$group))
library(scales)
g = ggplot(df, aes(combinedCategory, value, fill = type))
g = g + geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'fill')
g = g +   facet_grid(facet ~ .)
g = g + scale_y_continuous(labels  = percent)
g = g + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("X","Y"))
g = g + geom_text(aes(x=1.5,y=0.05, label="Day 1"))
g = g + geom_text(aes(x=3.5,y=0.05, label="Day 2"))
g = g + geom_text(aes(x=5.5,y=0.05, label="Day 3"))
g = g + theme_minimal()
g
```

This give the following:

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is sufficient to choose

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is sufficient to set `y = interaction(group, day)` in `aes()`. This was actually my first step, but I was wondering if something more precise existed. Apparently not: the only tricky point here is to create a 2nd level x-axis labels row. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Of course this is the answer to my question: it is exactly what I asked for.